# My M1 Air restarts at some random time after shutdown

Tags: apple-silicon, ventura

My M1 Air restarts at some random time after I shutdown -- thus it keeps on running forever.

I tried with the `sudo nvram AutoBoot=%00`, and this works, but I’ve got to do this before *every* shutdown. Any clues as how to fix this permanently?

Comment: Do you have this set to boot atva certain time every day?  Look under Power Settings

Comment: Like iPads, the M1 laptops are designed to be "always on". I wouldn't bother shutting it down, unless you're going to leave it for a month or more.

Comment: @Allan, Could you please tell me what to do in detail.

Comment: See Apple’s [Sleep and wake settings](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-sleep-and-wake-settings-mchle41a6ccd/13.0/mac/13.0) for a guide on how to do this.